# Enable multi-threading on Caffe2

Tags: python, cmake, caffe2

When compiling my program using Caffe2 I get this warnings:

```
[E init_intrinsics_check.cc:43] CPU feature avx is present on your machine, but the Caffe2 binary is not compiled with it. It means you may not get the full speed of your CPU.
[E init_intrinsics_check.cc:43] CPU feature avx2 is present on your machine, but the Caffe2 binary is not compiled with it. It means you may not get the full speed of your CPU.
[E init_intrinsics_check.cc:43] CPU feature fma is present on your machine, but the Caffe2 binary is not compiled with it. It means you may not get the full speed of your CPU.
```

Since I do want to get multi-threading support for Caffe2, I've searched what to do. I've found that Caffe2 has to be re-compiled setting some arguments while creating the `cmake` or in the `CMakeLists`.

Since I already had installed `pytorch` in a `conda` env, I have first uninstalled Caffe2 with:

```
pip uninstall -y caffe2
```

Then I've followed the instructions from the [Caffe2 docs](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=mac&configuration=compile), to build it from sources.
I first installed the dependencies as indicated. Then I downloaded `pytorch` inside my `conda` env with:

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git && cd pytorch
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

At this time I think is the moment to change the `pytorch\caffe2\CMakeLists` file just downloaded. I have read that in order to enable the multi-threading support is sufficient to enable the option `USE_NATIVE_ARCH` inside this `CMakeLists`, however I'm not able to find such option where I'm looking. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Here some details about my platform:

- I'm on macOS Big Sur
- My `python` version is `3.8.5`

**UPDATE:**

To answer Nega this is what I've got:

```
python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.__config__.parallel_info())'
ATen/Parallel:
    at::get_num_threads() : 1
    at::get_num_interop_threads() : 4
OpenMP not found
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.2 Product Build 20200624 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
    mkl_get_max_threads() : 4
Intel(R) MKL-DNN v0.21.1 (Git Hash 7d2fd500bc78936d1d648ca713b901012f470dbc)
std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : 8
Environment variables:
    OMP_NUM_THREADS : [not set]
    MKL_NUM_THREADS : [not set]
ATen parallel backend: OpenMP
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It turned out that the Clang that comes with XCode doesn't support OpenMP. The `gcc` that I was using was just a symlink to Clang. In fact after running `gcc --version` I got:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I installed from Homebrew `gcc-10` and set the alias like this `alias gcc='gcc-10'`. In fact now with `gcc --version` this is what I get:

```
gcc-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I've also tried a simple Hello World for OpenMP using 8 threads and everything seems to be working. However after re-running the command:

```
python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.__config__.parallel_info())'
```

I get the same outcome. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVX, AVX2, and FMA are CPU instruction sets and are not related to multi-threading. If the pip package for pytorch/caffe2 used these instructions on a CPU that didn't support them, the software wouldnt work. Pytorch, installed via `pip` comes with multi-threading enabled though. You can confirm this with `torch.__config__.parallel_info()`

```
❯ python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.__config__.parallel_info())'
ATen/Parallel:
    at::get_num_threads() : 6
    at::get_num_interop_threads() : 6
OpenMP 201107 (a.k.a. OpenMP 3.1)
    omp_get_max_threads() : 6
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.1 Product Build 20200208 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
    mkl_get_max_threads() : 6
Intel(R) MKL-DNN v1.6.0 (Git Hash 5ef631a030a6f73131c77892041042805a06064f)
std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : 12
Environment variables:
    OMP_NUM_THREADS : [not set]
    MKL_NUM_THREADS : [not set]
ATen parallel backend: OpenMP
```

That being said, if you still want to continue building pytorch and caffe2 from source, the flag your looking for, USE_NATIVE is in `pytorch/CMakeLists.txt`, one level up from `caffe2`. Edit that file and change USE_NATIVE to ON. Then continue building pytorch with `python3 setup.py build`. Note that the flag USE_NATIVE doesn't do what you think it does. It only allows the building of MKL-DNN with CPU native optimization flags. It does not trickle down to `caffe2` (except where `caffe2` use MKL-DNN obviously.)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm only interested in multi-threading. I've updated my answer to show you what I've got by running the command that you wrote. I think I'll have to install OpenMP first

Comment: I've updated my answer again making sure that I had OpenMP this time. However it is still not found by torch. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: all precompiled versions of pytorch should have OpenMP enabled 1) make sure your pip'd version of pytorch is up-to-date. 2) make sure you're _not_ running `python3 -c 'import torch; print(torch.__config__.parallel_info())'` inside any of the source directories that you recently downloaded

Comment: Unfortunately I did both but nothing. However thank you.